# java proxy method invocation with output arguments

Tags: java, reflection, methods, arguments

I have a problem. I created a new invocation handler and I would like set the (output) arguments of methods, but not successful. Thanks a lot!

My code:

```java
class MyInvocationHandler extends InvocationHandler {
      public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
                 if (method.getName().equals("example")) {
                     args[0] = "abcd"; //not successful
                     return "example";
                 }
      }
}
interface Test {
       String example(String s);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
          MyInvocationHandler myhandler = new MyInvocationHandler();
          Test test = (Test) Proxy.newProxyInstance(loader, new Class[]{Test.class}, myhandler);
          String a = new String("ab");
          String ret = test.example(a);
          System.out.println(a); //a value is ab, not abcd! Why?
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I would like to set the method arguments.
System.out.println(a); //a value will be "ab" after the method is invoked, not "abcd"! How to set the method arguments in the invocation handler when the method is invoked?